# What's the difference between regular and ml AWS EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

I'm experimenting with [AWS Sagemaker](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/) using a Free Tier account. According to the [Sagemaker pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/), I can use 50 hours of m4.xlarge and m5.xlarge instances for training in the free tier. (I am safely within the two-month limit.) But when I attempt to train an algorithm with the XGBoost container using m5.xlarge, I get the error shown below the code.

Are the ml-type and non-ml-type instances the same with just a fancy prefix for those that one would use with Sagemaker or are they entirely different? The [EC2 page](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) doesn't even list the ml instances.

```
sess = sagemaker.Session()

xgb = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(container,
                                    role, 
                                    instance_count=1, 
                                    instance_type='m5.xlarge',
                                    output_path=output_location,
                                    sagemaker_session=sess)
```

> ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the
> CreateTrainingJob operation: 1 validation error detected: Value
> 'm5.xlarge' at 'resourceConfig.instanceType' failed to satisfy
> constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [ml.p2.xlarge,
> ml.m5.4xlarge, ml.m4.16xlarge, ml.p4d.24xlarge, ml.c5n.xlarge,
> ml.p3.16xlarge, ml.m5.large, ml.p2.16xlarge, ml.c4.2xlarge,
> ml.c5.2xlarge, ml.c4.4xlarge, ml.c5.4xlarge, ml.c5n.18xlarge,
> ml.g4dn.xlarge, ml.g4dn.12xlarge, ml.c4.8xlarge, ml.g4dn.2xlarge,
> ml.c5.9xlarge, ml.g4dn.4xlarge, ml.c5.xlarge, ml.g4dn.16xlarge,
> ml.c4.xlarge, ml.g4dn.8xlarge, ml.c5n.2xlarge, ml.c5n.4xlarge,
> ml.c5.18xlarge, ml.p3dn.24xlarge, ml.p3.2xlarge, ml.m5.xlarge,
> ml.m4.10xlarge, ml.c5n.9xlarge, ml.m5.12xlarge, ml.m4.xlarge,
> ml.m5.24xlarge, ml.m4.2xlarge, ml.p2.8xlarge, ml.m5.2xlarge,
> ml.p3.8xlarge, ml.m4.4xlarge]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The instances with the `ml` prefix are instance classes specifically for use in Sagemaker.

In addition to being used within the Sagemaker service, the instance will be running an AMI with all the necessary libraries and packages such as Jupyter.

Comment: In that case, why does the free tier offer non-ml instances which doesn't work with Sagemaker?

Comment: Sagemaker includes its own free tier with an `ml.t3.medium`. This is also the minimum instance size that is currently supported. The reason will simply be the minimum requirements for running the required packages for the `ml` instance.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that's for running the notebook instance and not training using an algorithm-based container. (Please refer to the link I posted in my OP.)

Comment: There are other packages too, such as Docker which runs the training via AWS owned containers. Plus the orchestration software that is used by Sagemaker service to communicate and manage your instance :) And yes the free tier for training would be `ml.m5.xlarge`.

Comment: My question then is, if Sagemaker is specifically to be used with ml instances, then what does this mean?

`Training  50 hours of m4.xlarge or m5.xlarge instances`

(If you can't already guess, I'm trying not to spend any money with this experiment. :-) )

Comment: On the [Sagemaker pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/) page on the tab for training, it lists all the instances prefixed with `ml`. I believe the free tier has missed this in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, that's what's been confusing me. I'll take your word for it and give it a shot. Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 5):

The AWS EC2 instances with the **ml** prefix are specific EC2 instance classes for use in **AWS Sagemaker**.

Answer (score 0):

ml instances are optimized for machine learning. AWS sagemaker is also great to sharing code to setup machine learning, because other people can use the same ml instances. It requires more code and manual work to setup ec2 for machine learning and sharing becomes more difficult.